# Play a sound on UINavigationBar back button tapped

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

How do I play a sound ONLY when the "back" button is tapped in a UINavigationBar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do so, you will need to replace usual "back" button with new one, with your code of playing sound:

```
//in ViewDidLoad:

    UIBarButtonItem *barBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(pop:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barBtnItem;
    [barBtnItem release];

//action:
- (IBAction)pop:(id)sender {
    //your code of playing sound here
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

But note, that it will not look like usual "back" button. It will be rectangle. If you what it to look like usual "back" button, implement it like a custom button with cusom image (like usual "back" button)

Comment: is it not possible to just override popViewControllerAnimated?

Comment: I tryed to override usual "back" button - it is not possible. To override popViewControllerAnimated you will need to override navigation controller class to make it do what you need. I think  solution in my answer is much easier

Answer (score 1):

In your pop method you can play sound by :

```
- (IBAction)pop:(id)sender
{
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@”soundName” ofType:@”wav”];

    SystemSoundID soundID;

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath], &soundID);

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);

    [soundPath release];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```